Change Plotly-Dash DatePicker texts to Another Language
I have the following code:
    return html.Div([
        dcc.DatePickerRange(
            id=f'event-{col["id"]}-date-range',
            start_date_placeholder_text=translate("Start Date"),
            end_date_placeholder_text=translate("End Date"),
            display_format='DD/MM/YY',
            first_day_of_week=0,
            calendar_orientation='horizontal',
            is_RTL=True,
            clearable=True,
            with_portal=True,
            month_format='MMMM YYYY',
            day_size=40,
            min_date_allowed=date(2020, 1, 1),
            max_date_allowed=date(2025, 12, 31),
            initial_visible_month=date.today(),
            updatemode='bothdates'
        ),
        html.Div(id=f'event-{col["id"]}-localization-trigger')
    ], className='date-picker-container')
    ```

I am trying to set the language of the visible text to another language (Hebrew).

Is there a way to achieve this?


I found a workaround using MutationObserver:
(function() {
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        // Hebrew locale settings
        const hebrewMonths = [
            "ינואר", "פברואר", "מרץ", "אפריל", "מאי", "יוני", 
            "יולי", "אוגוסט", "ספטמבר", "אוקטובר", "נובמבר", "דצמבר"
        ];

        const hebrewWeekdays = [
            "ראשון", "שני", "שלישי", "רביעי", "חמישי", "שישי", "שבת"
        ];

        // Function to update calendar texts
        function updateCalendarTexts() {
            const monthElements = document.querySelectorAll('.CalendarMonth_caption');
            const weekdayElements = document.querySelectorAll('.DayPicker_weekHeader_li');

            // Update month names
            monthElements.forEach(function(el) {
                let monthText = el.textContent.trim();
                let monthIndex = window.moment().locale('en').month(monthText).month();  // Get month index
                if (monthIndex >= 0) {
                    el.textContent = hebrewMonths[monthIndex] + ' ' + el.textContent.split(' ')[1];
                }
            });

            // Update weekday names
            weekdayElements.forEach(function(el, index) {
                if (index < 7) {
                    el.textContent = hebrewWeekdays[index];
                }
            });
        }

        // Mutation Observer to watch for DOM changes
        const observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
            mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
                if (mutation.addedNodes.length || mutation.type === 'childList') {
                    // Trigger the text update when the calendar DOM is modified
                    updateCalendarTexts();
                }
            });
        });

        // Start observing the entire document (or a specific container if known)
        observer.observe(document.body, { childList: true, subtree: true });

        // Also trigger when a date picker is clicked (in case the calendar opens without DOM mutation)
        document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            if (e.target.closest('.DateInput_input') || e.target.closest('.DayPickerNavigation_button')) {
                setTimeout(updateCalendarTexts, 100);
            }
        });
    });
})();


